# Passing image to next activity when wi-fi is off

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, picasso

In my app,I store the image in SQLite and read read it from there. I can display it,in a recyclerview using picasso. But when I launch a new activity,by clicking a row,the image doesn't appear.

Here is my code.

From this adapter I get the image and the other data from the database.

```
public class MySQLAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MySQLAdapter.RowHolderClass> {

private List<SQLiteModel> myList;
private Context mContext;
private int focused;

public MySQLAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<SQLiteModel> ss) {
    this.myList = ss;
    this.mContext=activity;
}

@Override
public MySQLAdapter.RowHolderClass onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sqlite_adapter, null);

    final RowHolderClass holder = new RowHolderClass(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RowHolderClass holder, int position) {

    final SQLiteModel listItems = myList.get(position);
    holder.itemView.setSelected(focused==position);

    Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext())
            .load(myList.get(position).getSqliteImage()).into(holder.imageView);

    holder.fName.setText(myList.get(position).getSqliteFirstName());
    holder.lName.setText(myList.get(position).getSqliteSecondName());
    holder.jobRole.setText(myList.get(position).getSqliteRole());
    //holder.imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(myList.get(position).getSqliteImage()));
    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String first_name = listItems.getSqliteFirstName();
            String last_name = listItems.getSqliteSecondName();
            String job_role = listItems.getSqliteRole();
            String image_url = listItems.getSqliteImage();
            String id= String.valueOf(listItems.getSqliteId());
            //Log.v("id",id);

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, NoInternetDetailedActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("firstName",first_name);
            i.putExtra("lastName",last_name);
            i.putExtra("jobRole",job_role);
            i.putExtra("imageUrl",image_url);
            i.putExtra("memberId",id);

            mContext.startActivity(i);

        }
    });


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myList.size();
}


//ViewHolder pattern used to read the data of the row fast.
class RowHolderClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected ImageView imageView;
    protected TextView fName, lName, jobRole;
    protected RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    public RowHolderClass(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recLayout);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        this.fName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        this.lName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        this.jobRole = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.roleView);

    }
}
}
```

Then I pass the data in a new activity.

```
public class NoInternetDetailedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;

TextView textView0,textView1,textView2,textView3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_internet_detailed);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    String memberId = i.getExtras().getString("memberId");
    String firstName = i.getExtras().getString("firstName");
    String lastName = i.getExtras().getString("lastName");
    String jobRole = i.getExtras().getString("jobRole");
    String image = i.getExtras().getString("imageUrl");

    //imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newImageView);
    textView0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView0);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    textView0.setText("Member id: "+ memberId);
    textView1.setText(firstName);
    textView2.setText(lastName);
    textView3.setText(jobRole);

    //This line gives me the exception!
    Picasso.with(this).load(image).into(imageView);
  }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

 at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)

 at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: you are passing to NoInternetDetailedActivity not NewActivity ??

Comment: @Nisarg is right but the you should have a NullPointerException :S

Comment: I can't see the error, I'm thinking maybe is the context. try to pass the application context in both may be ?

Comment: See the exception I get in this line         Picasso.with(this).load(image).into(imageView); of the 
NoInternetDetailedActivity class

Comment: @Theo can you post your xml of NoInternetDetailedActivity ?

Comment: @Theo xml file of NoInternetDetailedActivity ?

Comment: @Theo Dude you have commented  //imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newImageView); please remove comment

Comment: Actually I had to uncomment the imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newImageView); So problem is fixed!!!

Comment: @Nisarg How can I remove a comment?

Comment: @Theo Press Ctrl+Shift+Slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*Use this aproach*/
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

 /* wifi is not enabled */

if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled()){

     imageView.buildDrawingCache();
     Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
}

/* Receive image on second activity */
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```